# Como criar um robô para testar o trafego no meu site em localhost?

Tags: robots.txt

Tenho um site mysite.com que está rodando num ambiente local LEMP (Linux, Nginx,MariaDB, PHP7). O site já está pronto e tenho um banco de dados bem carregado com muitos dados fake.

Antes de mandar para o AWS-EC2, quero testar alguns parâmetros de acessibilidade.

Entáo queria saber como criar um robô que irá simular vários acessos concorrentes ao meu site.

Eu quero prever qual o limite de usuários acessando o sistema no qual ele começa a perder o rendimento esperado.

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal usar o [ApacheBench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)?

Por exemplo:

```
$ ab -n 100 -c 5 http://www.google.com/
```

`-n`: Indica o número de requisições HTTP.

`-c`: Indica quantidade de conexões HTTP simultâneas.

Saída:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.google.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        www.google.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        260 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   1.217 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        87
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 87, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      100
Total transferred:      47848 bytes
HTML transferred:       26174 bytes
Requests per second:    82.18 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       60.842 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       12.168 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          38.40 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       24   28   2.9     28      39
Processing:    25   29   2.8     29      37
Waiting:       25   29   2.8     29      37
Total:         50   57   5.4     56      71

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     56
  66%     59
  75%     61
  80%     62
  90%     65
  95%     67
  98%     71
  99%     71
 100%     71 (longest request)
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: no caso do meu site tenho a primeira página - mysite.com com um login para o usuário acessar o sistema. Entáo essa sua abordagem testa somente a primeira página? tem como testar as paginas internas?

Comment: Nesse caso, o flag `-C` é capaz de passar um cookie de sessão para o `ApacheBech`, possibilitando esse tipo de teste. Outra ferramenta que poderia ajudar nesse sentido seria o JMeter.